# How can I determine how much white blank space I can crop without cropping any material, in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I must print  PDFs  over 500 pages and with footnotes. All pages are bordered by white blank space, but the white blank space start at different lengths from the border. To wit,  the cutoff and dimensions of the text and images differ for each  page.

It's too inefficient to measure the cutoff of white blank space on each page. How can I deduce the maximum crop size that'd eliminate the most white space, without cropping the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Sejda's [Crop PDF](https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf) tool.

It renders pages one on top of each other, blended, so you can maximize the crop box while making sure it will not cut out any of the page content.

[image: PDF pages rendered blended]

1. Open https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf
2. Select your PDF
3. Choose "Crop whole document"
4. Scroll down and click on "Blend all". By default just the first 30 pages are blended.
5. Make your crop selection (drag a rectangle with the mouse over the blended page)
6. Your measurements will show up in the top part of the page, in inches.

The crop tool is free to use 3 times per hour and for documents up to 200 pages and 50Mb. If you just want to measure the optimal crop area it is free to use.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Comment: "It renders pages one on top of each other, blended, so you can maximize the crop box while making sure it will not cut out any of the page content." For the free version, are there any page or size limits?

Comment: Neat feature.  Thanks for posting this.  Say the odd and even pages are shifted for the binding.  Is there a way to do odd and even pages as separate groups?

Comment: @fixer1234 Not yet, but that would be a great improvement, we'll consider making this easier.